# What is the purpose of requires_arc in a pod spec?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I am using a SDK from cocoapods and in its pod spec it says the "requires_arc" is set to true but in my project automatic reference counting is turned off.  So how is everything still working and building fine if the pod requires arc but my project has arc turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requires_arc` flag only applies to building the sources in the library defined by the podspec. It does not affect the build flags for the app that is including the pod.

Comment: ok thanks very much for the quick response will accept answer after the 11 minutes.  By the way it does not conflict with my project that the pods are being built with arc but my project isnt ?

Comment: Nope. They’re completely interoperable. You’re just manually doing the memory management that ARC does automatically for the code in the pods. You should make sure that you’re conforming to the ARC naming rules, though. The static analyzer (shift-command-B or “product” » “analyze”) should let you know if you have any issues.

Comment: when you say "conforming to the ARC naming rules" what exactly does this mean if I am not using ARC in my project ?

Comment: @Julian [_If the name of a class method that returns an object starts with **alloc**, **init**, or **new** you have to handle the returned object as you did a retain on it._](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529454/). This is officially described in more details in [Method families](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families)

Comment: @Julian - In addition to those three prefixes, methods whose names start with `copy` and `mutableCopy` must also return +1 objects. All other methods that return objects should return `autorelease` objects.